# How make Javascript code work for each element individually, to create multiple duplicates in HTML with same Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have created a simple image carousel that I am using on my site.

It all works well until I only have one but as soon as I try to create a new one it doesn't work properly.

All I need is that all the image sliders I create are independent of each other.

Both of the sliders should work individually.

Any help would be very great.

Here is my code:

```js
//current position
var pos = 0;
//number of slides
var totalSlides = $('.slider-wrap ul li').length;
//get the slide width
var sliderWidth = $('.slider-wrap').width();


$(document).ready(function(){
 
 
 /*****************
  BUILD THE SLIDER
 *****************/
 //set width to be 'x' times the number of slides
 $('.slider-wrap ul.slider').width(sliderWidth*totalSlides);
 
    //next slide  
 $('.next').click(function(){
  slideRight();
 });
 
 //previous slide
 $('.previous').click(function(){
  slideLeft();
 });
 
 
 
 /*************************
  //*> OPTIONAL SETTINGS
 ************************/
 //automatic slider
 var autoSlider = setInterval(slideRight, 3000);
 
 //for each slide 
 $.each($('.slider-wrap ul li'), function() { 
    //set its color
    var c = $(this).attr("data-color");
    $(this).css("background",c);
    
    //create a pagination
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    $('.pagination-wrap ul').append(li);    
 });
 
 //counter
 countSlides();
 
 //pagination
 pagination();
 
 //hide/show controls/btns when hover
 //pause automatic slide when hover
 $('.slider-wrap').hover(
   function(){ $(this).addClass('active'); clearInterval(autoSlider); }, 
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('active'); autoSlider = setInterval(slideRight, 3000); }
 );
 
 

});//DOCUMENT READY
 


/***********
 SLIDE LEFT
************/
function slideLeft(){
 pos--;
 if(pos==-1){ pos = totalSlides-1; }
 $('.slider-wrap ul.slider').css('left', -(sliderWidth*pos));  
 
 //*> optional
 countSlides();
 pagination();
}


/************
 SLIDE RIGHT
*************/
function slideRight(){
 pos++;
 if(pos==totalSlides){ pos = 0; }
 $('.slider-wrap ul.slider').css('left', -(sliderWidth*pos)); 
 
 //*> optional 
 countSlides();
 pagination();
}



 
/************************
 //*> OPTIONAL SETTINGS
************************/
function countSlides(){
 $('.counter').html(pos+1 + ' / ' + totalSlides);
}

function pagination(){
 $('.pagination-wrap ul li').removeClass('active');
 $('.pagination-wrap ul li:eq('+pos+')').addClass('active');
}
```

```css
/*GLOBALS*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1bc1a3;
}

body,
hmtl {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px 2px 0px;
}

.slider-wrap {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider li > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 35px;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider li > div h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider li > div span {
    font-family: Neucha, Arial, sans serif;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.slider-wrap ul.slider li i {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 90px;
}

.object-fit_contain {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}


/*btns*/

.btns {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    line-height: 57px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.next {
    right: -1px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.previous {
    left: -1px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.counter {}

.slider-wrap.active .next {
    right: 0px;
}

.slider-wrap.active .previous {
    left: 0px;
}


/*bar*/

.pagination-wrap {
    min-width: 20px;
    margin-top: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.pagination-wrap ul {
    width: 100%;
}

.pagination-wrap ul li {
    margin: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #3ab8cb;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.pagination-wrap ul li.active {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px 1px 0px;
}


/*Header*/

h1,
h2 {
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
    color: #7f8c8d;
    font-family: Neucha, Arial, sans serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/*ANIMATION*/

.slider-wrap ul,
.pagination-wrap ul li {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, .01, .32, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, .01, .32, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, .01, .32, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, .01, .32, 1);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, .01, .32, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ###########################  Slider 1  ##########################-->

<div class="slider-wrap">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li>
            <img class="object-fit_contain" src="http://www.spiritanimal.info/wp-content/uploads/Lion-Spirit-Animal-1.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="object-fit_contain" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/galleries/x701/156708.jpg">
        </li>

    </ul>

    <!--controls-->
    <div class="pagination-wrap">
        <div class="btns next"><i class="fas fa-greater-than"></i></div>
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <div class="btns previous"><i class="fas fa-less-than"></i></div>
    </div>
    <!--controls-->

</div>

<!-- ###########################  Slider 2  ##########################-->

<div class="slider-wrap">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li>
            <img class="object-fit_contain" src="http://www.spiritanimal.info/wp-content/uploads/Lion-Spirit-Animal-1.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="object-fit_contain" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/galleries/x701/156708.jpg">
        </li>

    </ul>

    <!--controls-->
    <div class="pagination-wrap">
        <div class="btns next"><i class="fas fa-greater-than"></i></div>
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <div class="btns previous"><i class="fas fa-less-than"></i></div>
    </div>
    <!--controls-->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID.  You will need to update your code to work off of class and "closest" related items if you need multiples of these on a single page.

For example, where you click "previous", you might need to change to something like:

```
//previous slide
$('.previous').click(function(event){
    slideLeft(event.target); // to pass the clicked 'previous' button to slideLeft()
});
```

Then in your slideLeft() function, find the slider by whichever one is ancestrally closest to the clicked button:

```
function slideLeft(target){
    pos--;
    if(pos==-1){ pos = totalSlides-1; }
    $(target).closest('.slider').css('left', -(sliderWidth*pos));   // only line I changed in your example

    //*> optional
    countSlides();
    pagination();
}
```

I did not run this fully but the concept of "know which one is clicked, then find what to update from there" is what you're going for I believe.

Comment: Yeah I know that is what I noticed too, but don't know how to deal with it. Do you have a code example for me?

Comment: Hi again, please have a look at the changes I have made in my code, I have converted all the ids into classes. I also tried that with the closest() but not working, or I wasn't able to implement it correctly. All I need is that all the image sliders I create are independent of each other.